# Cant POST or PUT. How do you change "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" to allow for these calls?

Tags: java, reactjs, cors

I know there are a bunch of answers out there for this issue.  But I just cant get past this.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/user/2' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

My get and delete routes work fine, but the post and put calls get this blocked by CORS error.

How and were do I edit my configs in my reactjs app to make this work?

I thought I already accounted for this issue in my Java controller.  I told the java server localhost:3000 is good to go.  Do I need something in my frontend to edit the header?

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = { "http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:4200" })
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/user/{id}")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Optional<User> user = repo.findById(id);
        if (id == -1) {
            return new User();
        }

        if (user == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return user.get();
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/user/{id}")
    public User deleteUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Optional<User> user = repo.findById(id);
        if (user == null) {
            return null;
        }

        repo.delete(user.get());
        return user.get();  
    } 

    @PutMapping("user/{id}")
    public User updateUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        User updatedUser = repo.save(user);
        return updatedUser;
    }

    @PostMapping("/user")
    public User addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        if (user == null) {
            return null;
        }

        User createdUser = repo.save(user);
        return createdUser;
    }
}
```

Heres is my js service code.  Im using axios to call the backend db routes

```
import axios from 'axios'

const USER_API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080'

class UserDataService {
    retrieveAllUsers() {
        return axios.get(`${USER_API_URL}/user`);
    }

    deleteUser(id) {
        console.log('excuted user deletion')
        return axios.delete(`${USER_API_URL}/user/${id}`);
    }

    getUser(id) {
        console.log('excuted user get')
        return axios.get(`${USER_API_URL}/user/${id}`);
    }

    createUser(user) {
        console.log('executed user create')
        return axios.post(`${USER_API_URL}/user)`, user);
    }

    updateUser(user) {
        console.log('executed user update')
        return axios.put(`${USER_API_URL}/user/${user.id}`, user);
    }
}

export default new UserDataService()
```

Comment: Can you see in network tab if the preflight request passes or not? or can you just share what you see in network? my guess is that you haven't configured Spring to accept preflight requests.

Comment: What am I looking for to see if the request is passing or not?

Comment: You can check to status code of your HTTP request.

Comment: You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check the HTTP status code of the response.